# Unable to use chart diagram in the NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I want to use a chart diagram in my right side navigation drawer. I am getting values from the server. Server response is ok. Problem is I am getting a NullPointerException. I am calling to **setMonthMatGroupSummery()** method from my Main Class.

This is the **Navigation Drawer class**.

```
public class MonthItemSummeryNavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerlayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";
    private String systemDate, oriSystemDate;
    private DateFormat df1, df2;
    private ArrayList<String> mGroupAchList;
    private float f;
    private HorizontalBarChart chart;
    private BarData barData;
    private ArrayList<String> aaa;

    public MonthItemSummeryNavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vieww = inflater.inflate(R.layout.matgroup_summery_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        chart = (HorizontalBarChart) vieww.findViewById(R.id.hchart);

        df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

        systemDate = df1.format(new Date());

        return vieww;
    }

    public void setMonthMatGroupSummery(ArrayList<String> r) {
        this.mGroupAchList = r;
        f = Float.parseFloat(mGroupAchList.get(0));
        Log.d("Array List f = ", String.valueOf(f));

        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("FG0028");
        xAxis.add("FG0015");
        xAxis.add("FG0010");
        xAxis.add("FG0009");
        xAxis.add("FG0005");
        xAxis.add("FG0004");
        xAxis.add("FG0002");
        xAxis.add("FG0001");

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d("Array List test = ", String.valueOf(f));
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // FG0028
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // FG0015
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // FG0010
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // FG0009
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // FG0005
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);
        BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // FG0004
        valueSet1.add(v1e6);
        BarEntry v1e7 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 6); // FG0002
        valueSet1.add(v1e7);
        BarEntry v1e8 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 7); // FG0001
        valueSet1.add(v1e8);


        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Ton");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);

        barData = new BarData(xAxis, dataSets);
        chart.animateXY(4000, 4000);
        chart.invalidate();
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        chart.setDescription("");
        chart.setData(barData);

        XAxis xAxiss = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxiss.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxiss.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xAxiss.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        YAxis yAxisLeft = chart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxisLeft.setDrawGridLines(true);
        yAxisLeft.setEnabled(false);
        YAxis yAxisRight = chart.getAxisRight();
        yAxisRight.setDrawGridLines(true);
        yAxisRight.setEnabled(false);
    }  

    }
}
```

My **LogCat**

```
06-10 14:51:50.277 14857-14857/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat, PID: 14857
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'void com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart.animateXY(int, int)' on a null object reference
at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.fragments
    .MonthItemSummeryNavigationDrawerFragment.setMonthMatGroupSummery(MonthItemSummeryNavigationDrawerFragment.java:128)
at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.WelcomeMenu.getMatGroupSummery(WelcomeMenu.java:740)
at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.WelcomeMenu$1.onResponse(WelcomeMenu.java:311)
at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.WelcomeMenu$1.onResponse(WelcomeMenu.java:257)
at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.json.CustomJsonObjectRequest.deliverResponse(CustomJsonObjectRequest.java:60)
at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.json.CustomJsonObjectRequest.deliverResponse(CustomJsonObjectRequest.java:17)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-10 14:56:38.185 14857-14857/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14857 SIG: 9
```

Comment: So you're declaring the `chart` object here, `chart = (HorizontalBarChart) vieww.findViewById(R.id.hchart);`. It must be `null` because `setMonthMatGroupSummery` is happening before `onCreateView`. Can you provide context as why that is happening?

Comment: Actually, I am getting the server response values form my Main class. I am using volley and in the onResponse i am sending values to *setMonthMatGroupSummery* in the navigation drawer class. If I calling the values from *onCreateView* no data coming

Comment: So you're calling `setMonthMatGroupSummery` before the drawer is ever instantiated?

Comment: `onResponce` may be called any time on the Response, So Its not sure that your `onCreateView` will be called at that time.. So better moving `chart = (HorizontalBarChart) vieww.findViewById(R.id.hchart);` inside `setMonthMatGroupSummery` as well.

Comment: @DanielK  no actually **setMonthMatGroupSummery** calling after calling the drawer. I tested it in my log cat..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna how can **vieww.findViewById(R.id.hchart);**  use inside a method??? It should initiated inside **onCreateView** method

Comment: Is there a way to initiated Drawer using setMonthMatGroupSummery() method?

Comment: Then how can you be sure that your  `onCreateView` is called before that method ?

Comment: You could pass a context, that's never advisable but you can.